# how to minimize unwanted/accident updates in the production database?

Tags: database, updates

how to minimize unwanted/accident updates in the production database ? prevent direct changes are done to the production database any suggestions or ideas will do. thank you

Comment: You mean: how to prevent 3rd parties modifying your production database? Just don't give them (write) access. Also seems like off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very open-ended question.  There are many levels at which it can be answered.

1. Operating system level.

   - Make sure that the files where the database is stored are secure from accidental tampering.
   - No public access to the files, but especially not write access.
   - No public access to the directories containing the files (or no write access again).
   - Only trustworthy people have O/S level access.
2. DBMS level.

   - Make sure that only trusted users have DB system administrator privileges.
3. Database level.

   - Make sure that only trusted users have DBA privileges.
   - Make sure that the general public can only modify the data in the tables they're supposed to modify.  That might well mean 'only SELECT access' for the general public.
   - Make sure that only selected users can modify (the data in) tables that the general public cannot modify.
   - Make sure that the correct integrity constraints are enforced by the DBMS.
   - Make sure that only trusted users can create stored procedures, modify table structures, etc.

Train those who are trusted.

Make sure you have an appropriate backup regimen in place.